# Showing exterior product is skew-commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I am learning about the exterior product and wish to show the skew commutative property. Here is my work:

[image]

I am confused on how to handle the notation of $(\omega^k \wedge \omega^l)$ as at the end I want to be able to write $(\omega^l \wedge \omega^k)$ How is this handled?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $\omega^k$ in standard basis $dx^1, dx^2,\ldots, dx^n$ and note that $dx^i\wedge dx^j=-dx^j\wedge dx^i$  for $i\neq j$ according to your note. now compute $w^k\wedge \omega^\ell$.

Try yourself, and then look at [Loring TU book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&lpg=PR1&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q&f=false) for direct proof.

Comment: Hi CFG, what is $dx^1$ and such? I've not seen this notation.

Comment: the coordinate chart components. for example in 2d we have $(x,y)$ and $dx$ and $dy$.

Comment: Hm, well, what comes to my mind is the standard dual basis for the $k$-form. I have been reading from: http://www.math.toronto.edu/jkamnitz/courses/mat247/tensorproducts1.pdf Is this the same thing?

Comment: yes. these are dual basis of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Comment: Okay, well, $\omega^k$ is a k-form on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. There is a basis for the $\omega^k$ $k$-form  consisting of $\alpha_1(\xi_1, \cdots , \xi_n)$ so that $\alpha_1(\xi_1, \cdots) = \xi_1$ and so forth. Meaning each member of $(V^{\star})^{\otimes k}$ is written as $\alpha_1 \otimes \alpha_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes \alpha_n$. Now I can do my permutation work as I did in the OP?

Comment: what is the $\alpha_1$? a $1$-form or $k$-form or $n$-form?

Comment: I'm...not sure. I was just writing the alphas to denote the dual basis of the dual vector space which the k-form lives in. I guess this is not correct.